# CellFormating event: changing Font row behaves like loop

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to change the font of a specific row  to Bold in DGV where there is "false" value in the column  (name"vu").

my code works but the problem is that the row behaves like there is loop (appears and disappears quickly and repeatly)

```cs
 private void DGV_boiteReception_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {

                DataGridViewRow row = DGV_boiteReception.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();

                style.Font = new Font(DGV_boiteReception.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

                if (row.Cells["vu"].Value.ToString() == "False")
                {

                    DGV_boiteReception.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle = style;

                }

        }
```

Comment: Instead of setting the full style try setting only the Font : `DGV_boiteReception.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.Font = style.Font;`

Comment: No this is not accepted by visual studio (Font have "get" only )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ought to work better:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender,
                                          DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = DGV_boiteReception.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    if (row.Cells["vu"].Value != null )
    {
        e.CellStyle.Font = new Font(DGV_boiteReception.Font,
                row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "False" ? 
                                                 FontStyle.Bold : FontStyle.Regular);
    }
}
```

I set only the `Font`, not the whole `Style` *(, and I only change the style of the currently formatting cell, as [recommended](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting?view=netframework-4.7.2).

I am also checking for null before testing the cell's value and I reset the fontstyle.

(*) For some reason this seems to make the difference wrt the continuous redraw you saw.

**If** your cell is a `Checkbox` cell you should also code these events:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Invalidate();
}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
}
```

And you ashould not that `True` and `False` are only for normal `CheckBoxes`.  If you set your checkbox to allow a 3rd state (`ThreeState = true`) the will be `Checked`, `Unchecked`and `Indeterminate`.

Comment: Thank you for the Solution , I'm not using a checkbox it's just a text (value from database sql server , type "bit" ).